# Use part of static URL to redirec to dynamic URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Usually is the other way aroud, but I need to redirect my static urls to dynamic ones as a variable part of the first one.

I need to redirect:

```
http:/example.com/sub1/sub-2/2014147-test-page-45x.html
http:/example.com/sub1/sub-6/8014149-test-24page.html
http:/example.com/sub1/sub-25/7514157-58test-page.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/sub1/testing.php?s=2014147
http://example.com/sub1/testing.php?s=8014149
http://example.com/sub1/testing.php?s=7514157
```

I know I need to use %{REQUEST_URI}, but I can't put it together.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub1/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /sub1/testing.php?s=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your .htaccess is at root of example.com, adding following to it will do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sub1/[^/]+/(\d+).*$ sub1/testing.php?s=$1 [R,L]
```